# AttributeError: and scope in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on an app using flask and redis. In my script I have:

```
import test

@app.route('/')
def main():
    test.main()
    return 'Hello World!'
```

in test.py, I have:

```
sr = StrictRedis()

def main():
......
......
```

If I step through my code within main(),  In the console I have:

```
>>> sr
StrictRedis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
>>> sr.members('myset')
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'StrictRedis' object has no attribute 'members'
```

I also notice that there is no autocompletion available when I type 'sr.'.

Is this related to python scope?

edit:

```
  >>> sr

  StrictRedis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
>>> sr.StrictRedis.smembers('UNTESTED')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\env\flenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-aefe6f099eac>", line 1, in <module>
    sr.StrictRedis.smembers('UNTESTED')
AttributeError: 'StrictRedis' object has no attribute 'StrictRedis'
```

still no attribute even if I type in it by hand. Interestingly if I type 'sr.'into the pycharm editor, I get all the methods and it works as expected.

Comment: Why do you expect the `StrictRedis()` instance to have a `members` attribute? I don't see it mentioned in the [documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: You can do a dir(sr) to see what attributes are available on it.

Comment: Thanks Brian - this shows that there are many methods available. I guess the problem is code completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with scope; you were able to access the `sr` name, which is where scoping ended and attribute lookups began.

Your `sr` object (an instance of the `StrictRedis` class) simply doesn't have a `members` attribute. The [`StrictRedis` documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis) doesn't seem to indicate that there should be any at all.

Perhaps you were looking for [`StrictRedis.smembers()` method](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.smembers) instead? Note the `s` at the start of the name; you are asking for ***s***et members:

```
sr.smembers('UNTESTED')
```

Comment: Thanks , but there are no attributes at all! Usually when I type 'sr.' I see a list of available classes, methods etc.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Python 2 itself doesn't offer autocompletion out of the box

Comment: I'm using  pycharm 4.5

Comment: @user61629: See [Pycharm: Code completion not giving recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15022804); you'll have to enable runtime type detection.

Comment: Thank you, tried that. but no change . Please see edit:

Comment: @user61629: it is `sr.smembers('UNTESTED')`.

Comment: @user61629: The method is defined by the `StrictRedis` class, but you'd call it on an instance of the class. We use that notation (`StrictRedis.smembers()`) because you could be using any name for an instance.

Comment: Yes that does work. Thanks for your help on this, but once again the code completion does not work. I'm going to accept this anyway.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) , there is no function `members()` for `StrictRedis` class.

I believe you meant to use - [`StrictRedis.smembers(<name>)`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.smembers)

> **smembers(name)**
>
> Return all members of the set name

Answer (score 1):

In your `StrictRedis()` class, may more like following code

```
# coding: utf-8
from redis import Redis

rs = Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
```

Did you use `ipython` to debug?  I suggest that you could try `set_trace()` in your code and inspect `rs`, maybe you need `ipdb` to help you find bugs ..

```
sudo pip install ipdb
```

then in your code, you could add this line

```
# coding: utf-8
from redis import Redis

rs = Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

when you exec code, it will stop here and you could debug step by step and it support autocompletion.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.