# AutoCode completion in pyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using a library called `Skype4Py`. Im dealing with a message object, but when I do `'msg.'` I cannot see the associated methods/metadata of that object like I can in eclipse when using java. Is this because python is a weakly typed language which makes auto code completion very hard?

Edit: I've turned on 'code completion' but it is not working in this case

Comment: I've found code completion to be hit-and-miss in PyCharm, RubyMine, and IntelliJ IDEA when it comes to scripted languages, honestly.

Comment: I notice it often works far better if you try it in the console...

Comment: In a live interpreter, tab completion is based on the actual object.

Comment: p.s. python is definitely not weakly typed. It is not *statically* typed.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60874856/4465708) doesn't help.