# How to enable code completion for a dictionary from method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm, code-completion

I am using Python 3.6 with PyCharm and it's kind of frustrating that there's no support for code completion for special cases of dictionary objects (with fixed key schema).

Say for example I create and try to access a simple dictionary object like this:

```
inventory = {'name': 'hammer', 'price': 2.3}
inventory['']
```

When I position my cursor inside the quotes ' ' and hit `Ctrl + Space` i get code completion and the IDE correctly suggests all the possible keys in the dictionary object. That's *great*!

But if i try to build it as a utility function that returns this same dict object, say with values that the user provide but with the same dict keys - then I don't get code completion anymore!

```
def get_inventory(name: str, price: float):
    return {'name': name, 'price': price}

inventory = get_inventory('hammer', 2.3)
inventory['']    # <- Pycharm can't offer any suggestions!
```

Any workaround or solution for this? I searched already for similar solutions but I didn't find anything that works. I know I can just convert it into a class `Inventory` and access the properties that way but I don't want to do it for a couple of reasons:

- I need the object to be easily JSON convertable since i might pass it from / to JSON a lot and `dict` objects are the easiest for this purpose
- storing it as a class wouldn't make much sense since i just need it as a data container anyway, with minimal properties stored within it

Any help or solution for how I can get my IDE to assist in code completion by recognizing the possible keys in such a `dict` object would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15022934/8150371

Comment: this proposed solution doesn't do anything for me ... even with that option ticked when i'm building code and trying to access from the dict object by key, i still get the 'No suggestions' output and will still have to manually enter it.

Comment: you can always try other IDE's like Visual Studio

Comment: You can use JSON as easily with most objects (of user-defined type) just as easily as with a `dict`—just call `vars` to get the dict, possibly combined with `dict.update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now mid-2023, and still no ways for PyCharm to detect *dynamic* `dict` keys returned from a function `def` exist.

However, there is a "sort" of workaround that is now possible. I realized that I forgot to mention it, so including it here.

Note that I say it's kind of a workaround, because this approach only works for *static* dict keys, rather than *dynamic* keys populated within a function scope. But hey, it's better than nothing.

### Using builtin `dict`

In **Python 3.8+**, this can now be achieved using `TypedDict`, as shown below. Also added a `__future__` import to account for annotations that could potentially be undefined at runtime, based on usage below.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, TypedDict


# To avoid creating a class at runtime, for type-hinting alone.
if TYPE_CHECKING:

    # Map the `dict` fields here
    class Inventory(TypedDict):
        name: str
        price: float


def get_inventory(name: str, price: float) -> Inventory:
    return {'name': name, 'price': price}


inventory = get_inventory('hammer', 2.3)

inventory['']    # <- suggestions now work in PyCharm!
```

### Dot-Access Dict - w/ fast performance

If **dot or attribute access** is desirable -- such as `a.b.c` instead of `a['b']['c']` -- then I have created a helper library [`dotwiz`](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io/) to achieve this, as shown below:

```py
import dotwiz
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


# To avoid creating a class at runtime, for type-hinting alone.
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from dataclasses import dataclass

    # Map the `dict` fields here
    @dataclass
    class Inventory:
        name: str
        price: float

else:
    Inventory = dotwiz.DotWiz


def get_inventory(name: str, price: float) -> Inventory:
    return Inventory(name=name, price=price)


inventory = get_inventory('hammer', 2.3)

print(inventory)
assert inventory.price == 2.3

inventory.    # <- suggestions now work in PyCharm!
```

Answer (score 5):

PyCharm has no idea what a `dict` contains because its keys and values are denoted at runtime. So you have to somehow hint PyCharm about the keys of `dict` beforehand. [Prodict](https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict) does exactly this to hint PyCharm, so you get the code completion.

```
class Inventory(Prodict):
    name: str
    price: float


def get_inventory(name: str, price: float):
    return Inventory(name=name, price=price)


inventory = get_inventory('hammer', 2.3)
print(inventory.name)
print(inventory.price)
```

In the above code, both `name` and `price` attributes are auto-completed.

Since Prodict is derived directly from `dict`, so you can use it as a regular `dict`.

This is the screenshot from the Prodict repo that illustrates code completion:

[image: Prodict code completion]

**PS**: I am the author of the Prodict.

Comment: Great tool. I think it would be helpful to let others know what exactly is making the IDE know about the dict beforehand. Is it the overridden `__dir__` method or something and where is it in your code?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij it will take too much space to explain how it works. The code resides in the github link behind the name of the package Prodict (https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict )