# How Debug with Python

Tags: python

I am a Java developer and today I started with Python (v3.7, using PyCharm). I tried to create a "hello world" application with a single package (`boto3`):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
client.  # unlike java, no suggestion (method or attribute of client object) from the IDE
```

I read [PyCharm code completion not giving recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022804/pycharm-code-completion-not-giving-recommendations) and I understand that due to the dynamic typing PyCharm is unable to determine the type of `client` and consequently it can not make any suggestion (e.g. methods or attributes of the object).

Hence, during debugging I was forced to look up the documentation to identify the attributes and methods of returned objects. This was error-prone and effort-full (e.g. typos or I assumed a different type of object resulting in `attribute not found` errors during execution).

Then, I was executing my code in the debug mode: I tried to identify attributes and methods of the returned objects in the evaluation box which is inconvenient too.

How do you handle such situations in Python? Do you have a good reference?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your editor behaves strangely (or if you don't have IDE e.g. on server) you can use the code itself because the maintainers might have included the documentation in the code and generate the webpage/PDF from the code itself. In those cases it's always worth trying `help()` on a particular object such as:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
help(boto3)
help(client)
```

but that works only if there is a docstring (code documentation) present which is not guaranteed. For such cases use these functions:

- [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to determine object's type
- [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to list all names (variables, functions, ...) in the object
- [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to list the object properties stored in [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) attribute

and in case you encounter something more tricky e.g. an object without `__dict__` attribute, always check with `dir()` because such object might use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__slots__) to be more efficient than basic `__dict__`. That's very common with C/C++/Cython extensions and will cause `vars()` function to fail with an error:

> `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`

This is also efficient on module level:

```
import boto3
dir(boto3)
```

which is handy for using directly in a console. That should your editor do and apparently does not for some reason.

There is also a case where a module behaves strangely (can't find the example, but happened to me in the past) and unlike importing under the containerized "variable" such as `boto3` it'd leak other symbols to the global variables.

That can be easily debugged with [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or even [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) if you import within a function.

Once the code becomes annoying enough, just jump into a [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) debugger which allows you to reexecute the code in much saner way than manually re-running the program and waiting for a message in the console which might not even show (e.g. condition not met or so).

Comment: No, I mostly remember the most common packages I use and either open a documentation on the side or within the editor. However, IDE won't help you in tricky cases where the code behaves strangely, therefore you'll eventually need to use type/dir/vars/... functions to figure out what's happened and it's much much faster to just drop a print bomb to the logs than to scratch the head :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in Python to give your IDE hints

```
import boto3

client: boto3.Session = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
```

Now when you type `client.` you should get hints

This is especially useful if you would like to perform static analysis of your code and have added type annotations to all of your methods

Comment: In this case, yes. Most mature/up-to-date packages have already added type annotations to their code base and have done this work for you