# What should I do to Pycharm code suggestion?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6K8E.png)
I'm a newbie in Python. I use Pychram to code. When I type 'pri' in Win 10, Pycharm suggests 'print'. But in Ubuntu 20, Pycharm doesn't do like that. I already set in Code Completion but it does not work.What can I do?

My English is bad, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

@Gareth_Latty says the following in another similar post.

"
As Python is a dynamically typed language, you need to ensure it can work out what type things are, and inspect on the libraries on your system correctly. Try to make sure it's obvious what type the object is in your code.

One good way as of PyCharm 2.7 (back when versions were numbers) is to enable runtime type detection - PyCharm hooks into your program while it runs (while debugging), and checks the types of variables as they are used.

You can enable this by going to settings, going to the "Build, Execution, Deployment" section and then the "Python Debugger" subsection and enabling "Collect run-time types information for code insight"."

Please make sure to research and look at other posts. Thank You!

[Make sure you check out this website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html) and [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022804/pycharm-code-completion-not-giving-recommendations)