# Intellij code completion on dot symbol is very slow compared to regular

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, ide

I am working with Python in Intellij version 2020, and I noticed something about the code completion.

You can see that regular text has code completion listed right away, but whenever I press `.`, it takes considerably longer to show.

Which setting can fix this?

[image]

I already have this setting selected:
[image: c]

Comment: What's the exact IDE version? Does it still happen in 2020.2 release? If so, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and provide the CPU snapshot: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235.

Comment: I havent used it for a while but I have the 2020.1 release, maybe it will be fixed when I update it

Comment: There were known issues affecting completion performance, please update and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get it to be amazingly fast, but this suggestion helped:

[image]

[Pycharm: Code completion not giving recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022804/pycharm-code-completion-not-giving-recommendations)