# Objects don't show available methods

Tags: python, pycharm

```
req = requests.get("google.com")
```

When I use the above command and I try to use the req variable, the IDE doesn't give me the available methods for the object - which is a `requests.response` object. Any hint would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you try ``print(repr(req))``?

Comment: i have but how would that help me? `repr(req)` gives me the status code and `type(req)` gives me pip._vendor.request.models.Response

Comment: Does this answer your question? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-what-methods-a-python-object-has

Comment: @Cyrus, that question is 12 years old. i am hoping updates were made since then. i just want autocomplete/intellisense to tell me the available methods for the object. in other languages and IDE's it's normally a drop down that appears

Comment: Why don't you just use dir() ?

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas, i looked up the `dir()` method. i see how 'print(dir(ObjName))' gives you a list of methods, but i am looking for something on the run - while i am typing. is this not available on pycharm? its basically intellisense.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas, i added a picture. why is it the object `req` doesnt show available methods for the class ?

Comment: @user1504725 Try to check the settings there i have to use a long time pycharm. **Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion > Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc.** Hope that helps.

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas, didnt work. ty

Comment: @user1504725 give a loot at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022804/pycharm-code-completion-not-giving-recommendations)

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas, i figured out the issue. the version of python i was using was 3.8. i updated to 3.9.2. Either it was a bad install or incompatible version. but it works now. ty for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Download and installed the newest python package - `https://www.python.org`
`File` -> `Settings` -> `Project:<ProjectName>` -> `Python Interpreter` -> select version.